# JavaFX 2 media compatibility?

Tags: java, javafx

I am using the JavaFX 2.2.5 to play local audio files in my application using the [Media](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/index.html?javafx/scene/media/Media.html) and [MediaPlayer](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/index.html?javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.html) classes. I found documentation for for [supported file types for JavaFX 1.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/1.3/tutorials/media-platforms-formats/#audio) but cannot find one for version 2 or above. Does anyone know of such documentation for version 2 or confirmation that this information applies for it as well?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html

Comment: @invariant Why not post that as an answer? That's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oracle documentation for JavaFX Media package  `javafx.scene.media` contains what you need :)    : [JavaFX2 Media](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html)